# Why such a bad map using a depth camera?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently bought D435 (Intel realsense) and used rtabmap package to perfrom SLAM.

I simply used this roslaunch:

http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping

And the result is this:

[image: image description]

The environment is this:

[image: image description]

Any ideas?

DB:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cZOOhW2TI5_lVt2W8VfuYakOA-6MSUio/view?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317195/why-such-a-bad-map-using-a-depth-camera?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on 2019-03-03**:
Was this running on a real robot? Not in gazebo?

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-03**:
@kitkatme Yes, but worth to note that I just used my camera without any external odometry.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-03**:
Is the camera immobile or you moved the camera? What kind of trajectory? If the camera is not moving, the noise in the cloud is coming from the sensor.

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-05**:
@matlabbe I did move the camera forward

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-05**:
Can you share the resulting database? (default ~/.ros/rtabmap.db)

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-06**:
@matlabbe I have added DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thx for the db, there are some observations that we can make (referring to figure below):

- The camera is very close to ground, so that the field of view is filled with more than 50% of repetitive symmetric pattern, very difficult to get good depth estimation as well for visual odometry. It is why the ground is poorly represented in the occupancy grid.
- The resulting depth image from the sensor is quite noisy (see top view of the cloud on right image). I suggest to use `Grid/3D=false` and `Grid/RayTracing=true` to get more empty cells (see grid on left image):

  ```
    $ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start --Grid/3D false --Grid/RayTracing true" depth_topic:=/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw rgb_topic:=/camera/color/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/camera/color/camera_info approx_sync:=false
  ```
- There is quite motion blur when the robot moves (see top middle image, open image in another tab to zoom in), which would affect visual odometry accuracy.

[image: image description]

Possible solutions:

- Tilt the camera toward the ceiling (and/or increase height) so that there is less ground in the FOV of the camera. Make sure to update TF as well between base_link and camera_link.
- Move slower to limit motion blur
- Consider using wheel odometry if possible

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-06**:
@matlabbe That is what I thought, probably ground is too close. Thank you for your help.